# How to provide link to Partial text

Tags: drupal-7

I want to give a link to my text Not Registered?Register Here.
I want to give link to Register Here n not to full text.
I am currently working on drupal 7 and i dont want to use html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to achieve this.

```
print t("Not Registered? !regurl", array('!regurl' => l(t('Register Here'), "user/register")));
```

Hope this helps you.